# runaway regular expression error in awk

Tags: command-line, bash, awk

I have a script which converts expressions in different units to standard units like:
distance=1km -> distance=1000m.

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat "$1" | grep '=' | awk -F= '{switch ($2) {
                    case  /^[0-9]+s$/ : print $1"="$2*1;
                    break;
                    case /^[0-9]+min$/ : print $1"="$2*60;
                    break; 
                    case /^[0-9]+h$/ : print $1"="$2*3600;
                    break;
                    case /^[0-9]+d$/ : print $1"="$2*3600*24;
                    break;
                    case /^[0-9]+mm$/ : print $1"="$2/1000;
                    break;
                    case /^[0-9]+sm$/ : print $1"="$2/100;
                    break;
                    case /^[0-9]+dm$/ : print $1"="$2/10;
                    break;
                    case /^[0-9]+m$/ : print $1"="$2*1;
                    break;
                    case /^[0-9]+km$/ : print $1"="$2*1000;
                    break;
                    case /^[0-9]+mg$/ : print $1"="$2/1000000;
                    break;
                    case /^[0-9]+g$/ : print $1"="$2/1000;
                    break;
                    case /^[0-9]+kg$/ : print $1"="$2*1;
                    break;
                    case /^[0-9]+t$/ : print $1"="$2*1000;
                    break; }
                }'
fi
```

But when I'm trying to run it I have two errors:

```
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near {
awk: line 2: runaway regular expression / : print $ ...
```

Comment: What does your input file look like? Why do you have a `fi` at the end of your script? That should give you a different error from what you show.

Comment: Are you using GNU Awk (`gawk`), or some other implementation - perhaps `mawk`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain that the error is because your system is configured to use `mawk` (which currently does not appear to support the `switch ... case` construct) as the default implementation of `awk` - rather than `gawk` (GNU Awk):

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set awk /usr/bin/mawk
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/mawk to provide /usr/bin/awk (awk) in manual mode
$ 
$ echo 'abc:123' | awk -F: '{switch($2) {case /^[0-9]+$/: print $1; break;}}'
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near {
awk: line 1: runaway regular expression /: print $1 ...
```

whereas with GNU awk

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set awk /usr/bin/gawk
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/gawk to provide /usr/bin/awk (awk) in manual mode
$ 
$ echo 'abc:123' | awk -F: '{switch($2) {case /^[0-9]+$/: print $1; break;}}'
abc
```